# Variance of one die with binary result

Tags: variance, dice

I have a task that is worded:
"You have a deciding die-throw ahead of you in a game (using a fair 6-sided die) and you realize that you will win if you get a 4 and lose in every other case. You quickly calculate your expected number of wins from this throw, but what is the variance?"

The expected number of wins is 1/6 but I do not understand what they mean when they ask for variance.
Do they ask for the variance of the number of dots on the die? In that case, I suppose it is
$ \sum_{k=1}^{6} (k^2*P(X=k)) - E(X)^2$, correct?

Or are they asking for the variance of winning vs losing? In that case, how do you calculate it? Since the prob. for losing is 5/6 and winning is 1/6 using:
[image]

gives $\frac{(5/6)^2+(1/6)^2}{2}-1/36=12/36$. Is this the variance they are asking for?

Comment: You’re basically flipping an unfair coin. Approach the problem that way, and you should be able to solve it.

Comment: Meaning the variance is npq=1*(1/6)*(5/6), correct? Which would mean $E(X^2)=6/36$. How is that?

Comment: It's unclear what you might mean by "$X.$"  In this context, it would be natural to work with a random variable that indicates whether you win or lose.  The actual numbers printed on the die are irrelevant.  For instance, suppose the problem were changed to "you use a fair six-sided die with the letters 'A' through 'F' printed on its faces and you will win only if you roll a 'D'" This is obviously of no consequence for the answer -- but what would your random variable $X$ be now??